# rpc security information for publisher is missing

Tags: sql-server

i use sql server 2008 for publisher and sql server 2005 express for subscriber , 
when i insert to a table from my subscriber this error occur :

```
   Msg 21079, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_getpublisherlink, Line 52
The RPC security information for the Publisher is missing or invalid. Use sp_link_publication to specify it.
Msg 20512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSreplraiserror, Line 8
Updateable Subscriptions: Rolling back transaction.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

when insert to table from publisher all thing is ok .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the link on the subscriber. Run this on your subscriber database.

```
sp_link_publication @publisher = '{publisher instance name}'
, @publisher_db = '{published database name}'
, @publication = '{publication name}'
, @security_mode = '1'
, @login = '{sql server login account to connect publisher}'
, @password = '{password}'
, @distributor = '{distributor instance name}'
```

Comment: thnx but this error occur :  login failed . the login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication .

Comment: this error solved , only login to subscriber with sql authentication and then run above sp_link_publication and now all thing is ok